# ASP.NET Identity, Allow Only One Authenticated User in Server

Tags: asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-identity-2

I implemented ASP.net Identity 2.1.0 authentication in my MVC5 applicaiton. I'm looking for a way to only allow one connection at a time per username/password combination. For example, if someone with the username `A` and password `B` connects, until they disconnect, anyone attempting to connect as `A` with password `B` will be rejected with a message along the lines of "There is an active user logged in with that information!".
I've tried using `CookieAuthenticationProvider.OnValidateIdentity` and `CookieAuthenticationProvider.OnResponseSignIn` but I don't know how to detect the active user's session.

I found [a post](https://timmlotter.com/blog/asp-net-identity-invalidate-all-sessions-on-securitystamp-update/) with something similar, but instead of rejecting the first connection with the same credentials it invalidates the connection when the password is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem by generating a new GUID each time a user logs on and store that in the user's session and in the authentication token. On each request or at a certain interval, you can compare the two and if they don't match, you can log the user out.

With this approach you when a user logs in from a second browser/device you can prompt them with a message indicating they are currently logged in elsewhere and that session will be logged out if they continue.